# Populate textbox with table entry plus one?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to increment project number based on the last entry. The the primary key PROJECTNOID auto-increments but is not the same format as the project number (Ex: PROJECTNOID = 1 and Project Number = 19000). I don't want this to be a dropdown box even though some of my code shows the opposite.

```
<?php
   connect = mysqli_connect("**", "**", "**", "**");

   $query4 = "SELECT PROJECTNOID, ProjectNumber FROM tblProjects ORDER BY 
              PROJECTNOID";
   $result4 = mysqli_query($connect,$query4);

   $options4 = "";

   while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_row($result4);){
      $options4 = $options4."<input value=$row4[0]$row4[1]</input>";
   }

?>
```

Here is the html textbox:

```
<label for="txtfield">Project Number</label>
            <!--<input type="text" id="reqtxtfield" name="projectnumber" 
value="<?php  ?>" readonly/>-->
              <?php echo $options4;?>
```

Comment: The missing quote on the mysqli_connect is just a typo.

Comment: Just stuck that `"` in - the failure on SO's syntax highlighting was bugging me...

Comment: `<input value=$row4[0]$row4[1]</input>` that's going to create some slightly broken HTML, like: `<input value=119000</input>`

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: So im trying to have it display the ProjectNumber but be assigned the value of PROJECTNOID. So it will have '19000' in the text box but when i submit the sheet it will fill out '1'

Comment: Ah. OK. First, you need to clean up a few things. Looks like you're trying to generate multiple `<input>` elements. One for each entry, right? You could put them into an array and then to output them, loop over the array and generate an `<input>` for each iteration. But to answer your question directly, you can `$options4 = $options4.'<input value="' . $row4[0] . '">' . $row4[1] . '</input>';`

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Actually, please disregard my previous comment. `<input>Text</input>` is **not** valid HTML. Did you just want the Project Number printed out next to the `<input>` element?

Comment: Yes but I need the value of PROJECTNOID associated with it too

Comment: @JordanMack - I'm a little confused about this comment, `I don't want this to be a dropdown box even though some of my code shows the opposite.`. In your comments, you allude to `value` Vs. `text`. `<input>` elements only have a `value` attribute. `<select>` elements have both `value` and `text`. Using https://jsfiddle.net/w31075jc/, can you please show us the desired result? Or even better, update your question showing the desired result. Don't worry about how to code it, for now, we can help with that. Just show us what you want the result to look like. Ie. the HTML.

Comment: @waterloomatt - sorry, im not sure how to upload that link back into here. But it would look like how you had it but instead of '1' inside the box it would display '19000' and there would be nothing outside of the box other than the label "Project Number". As far as i'm aware you can assign a value to the text box, regardless of whatever the input is. I would like it to display the value from one field name but actually contain the value from a different field name. Both are in the same table of course.

Comment: @waterloomatt [jsfiddle.net/jmack_37/w31075jc/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/jmack_37/w31075jc/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP:

```
<?php
  $query_5 = "SELECT MAX(ProjectNumber) FROM tblProjects;";
  $result_5 = mysqli_query($conn, $query_5);
  $row_5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_5);
  $nextproject=$row_5['MAX(ProjectNumber)']+1;
?>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <form class="myform" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]);?>" method="post">
  <label for="txtfield">Project Number</label>
     <input type="text" id="reqtxtfield" name="projectnumber" value="<?php echo $nextproject ?>" readonly/><br>
```

After running successful insert query:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";  //REFRESH PAGE TO UPDATE PROJECT NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

> But it would look like how you had it but instead of '1' inside the
>   box it would display '19000' and there would be nothing outside of the
>   box other than the label "Project Number". As far as i'm aware you can
>   assign a value to the text box, regardless of whatever the input is. I
>   would like it to display the value from one field name but actually
>   contain the value from a different field name. Both are in the same
>   table of course.

OK - gotcha. Unfortunately, you cannot do that. A textbox can only have one value and the user is always free to change that value, *even if you make it read-only*. You can test that out by using the developer toolbar in your browser. Probably a good time to mention that all user input should be considered dangerous and you should never trust it. Once they have submitted the form you need to verify it.

[image: change value through developer toolbar]

What I would recommend in your case is to use a hidden `<input>` which contains the value you actually want to submit; projectnoid. You can then display the Project Number in any manner you choose.

```html
<form>
        <h1>Project Number: 19000</h1>
        <input type="hidden" name="projectnoid" value="1">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

To generate this, you would:

```
<?php
while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_row($result4)){

    $projectnoid = $row[0];
    $projectNumber = $row[1];

    echo '<h1>' . $projectNumber . '</h1>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="projectnoid" value="'. $projectnoid .'">
}
```